# Raspberry Pi zero w WiFi not discoverable on boot

Tags: wifi, pi-zero-w

I've been using a Raspberry Pi 3B to write some scripts and I setup an access point for WiFi setup using Balena's WiFi connect. I'm trying to transfer over to the sleek Pi Zero W. However, I notice when I bootup WiFi connect failed to connect the device to a network stating that no networks are available. When I check the WiFi status with network manager

```
nmcli device wifi show
```

No, networks are displayed except Wifi Connect. If I then input

```
nmcli radio wifi off
nmcli radio wifi on
nmcli device wifi show
```

The networks become discoverable and I can manually connect to one. However, my Wifi connect app is turned off in the process. This there a way to keep the wifi discoverable on ? I never had this problem with the Raspberry Pi 3B, it always discovered networks on boot.

Comment: If you choose to install other network managers don't expect the default dhcpcd tools to work.

Comment: Fair enough, is a reasonable solution to write a script to run terminal commands on boot using perhaps python subprocess module?

Comment: A more reasonable solution is to use the inbuilt tool, which works very well. Network Manager is the last thing I would inflict on my Pi.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Balena Wifi Connect requires the Network Manager and disables dhcpcd on install, otherwise I would be more than happy using the inbuilt tools